# How to keep one object on certain view mode?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, wireframe

I'm trying to keep my reference image that I important as a plane in **Material** mode while I can still adjust the object I'm modeling by switching between **Wireframe** and **Solid** (by using Z). Every time I hit Z the reference image goes to wireframe/solid. How do I go about this? Google is yielding no results, or I just don't know the proper terms to use for searches. I am using Blender Cycles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the object properties there is an option called maximum draw type. Set this to wire. It will display the object as wire like the wire view mode, although a handful of things are different regarding selection in edit mode and such.

[image]

If you want to select the object like in wireframe mode as well, you can turn off limit selection to visible:

[image]

Comment: This does not give all the benefits of working in wireframe mode, however. If you try to select verts from the back side of the model with box select, they will not be selected. The points are still occluded by the object, despite being able to see them. If you change to wireframe mode, the points will be selectable again. I want to bring this up with the developers and see if we can get it changed.

Comment: @Italic_ The OP's issue was not being able to see the background issue. Limit selection to visible can also be turned of if the OP wants to have the selection ability of wireframe mode. Side-note: Because we have the limit selection to visible option, I would **not** be happy to have the maximum Draw Type have the same selection modes as wireframe, since how would, if I wanted to, Have the object in wireframe and limit selection to visible functioning. I wouldn't take this up with the devs.

Comment: Since there's the limit toggle, I guess it wouldn't be necessary. It's not very intuitive, though, because wireframe _only_ allows selection through the whole model, not occluded selection, so by allowing the occluded selection it breaks convention with the other mode and UI. Telling us both are wire is not entirely true because they don't behave the same.

Comment: @Italic_ No they don't behave the same... I never meant it like that  however, since it could be an issue, I will point it out.

Comment: Looks like a good edit. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use an *Image Empty* for your reference image.  Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Empty* > *Image*.  Then go the empty's settings in the properties view and open the image you want to use.  The empty will display the image no matter what viewport shading mode you are using.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For 2.8 and up:

- Click the object
- Click to `Object Properties`
- Drop down `Viewport Display`
- Drop down `Display As`
- Choose how to display the item while in the viewport

Screenshot:
[image]