# LookDev only one object shows material rendering

Tags: rendering

I am using Blender 2.8 and viewing this ink bottle object I made in LookDev shading mode but the rendering materials wont show up.

The circular plane shows the rendering and has the same materials as the bottle.

[image]

[image]

Comment: does https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41230/how-to-keep-one-object-on-certain-view-mode?rq=1 help? It is possible that the maximum draw type of the bottle has been set to solid.